# How to use a public-nested interface, used in its own class?

Tags: c#

I was looking through some github projects on AI.
I saw an interesting implementation, that i wanted to try.

Basically, it allows the implemented algorithms to be used by different games, using generic interfaces.
Here is the general idea :

```
public static class TreeSearch<TGame, TMove, TPlayer>
    where TGame : TreeSearch<TGame, TMove, TPlayer>.IGame
{
    public interface IGame :
        ICurrentPlayer<TPlayer>,
        IDoMove<TMove>,
        IGameOver,
        ILegalMoves<TMove>,
        IUndoMove,
        IScore<TPlayer>
    { }

    public static TMove GetBestMove(TGame game)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class implement its own interface `IGame`, congregation of many other interface representing the "base interaction" of a game.
As i understand it, this is useful to specify what are **exactly** the requirements for the game, as the algorithms each have different needs, and thus different interface requirements.

I decided to implement it, and did it like so :

```
public class GameLogic :
        ICurrentPlayer<Player>,
        IDoMove<Move>,
        IGameOver,
        ILegalMoves<Move>,
        IUndoMove,
        IScore<Player>
{
    // Implementation of ICurrentPlayer, IDoMove, ...
}
```

I use each interfaces directly, as i want my game to be able to use many AI algorithms.

However, i'm quite stuck at how i'm supposed to use it :

```
Move move = TreeSearch<GameLogic, Move, Player>.GetBestMove(instanceOfGameLogic);
```

It doesn't work like this, because `GameLogic` isn't directly using `TreeSearch.IGame`. 
I could replace the list of interfaces in `Gamelogic` with `TreeSearch.IGame`, but i don't want to have a strong reference to each AI algorithms (like `TreeSearch`) that i will use. Also, i find that it decrease the readability.

**Is there a way to use the algorithms, without having to implement `IGame` in `GameLogic`?**

Comment: Are you sure your first code block is correct? Surely it must use `TPlayer` and `TMove` not `Player` and `Move`?

Comment: @Jamiec Right, i made a typo, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that, in order to use the `GetBestMove` method, your game logic *must* implement the interface `IGame` defined, as there is a generic constraint mandating that:

```
...
where TGame : TreeSearch<TGame, TMove, TPlayer>.IGame
```

Comment: Ok. So i removed the reference to IGame, and use the list of interfaces there. It effectively works, and i keep the list of requirements.
I now realise that i what focused on finding a magic way of declaring the use of IGame outside of the class...
Thanks.